# Unable to combine PySimpleGUI and Turtle in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, python-turtle, pysimplegui

I was combining `PySimpleGUI` and `Turtle` in Python, but after calling `done()`, Python wouldn't close properly like isn't finished with code. I have a similar code which just uses the `Turtle` part and works as expected, I am not really sure what the issue is here.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from turtle import *
from math import *
sg.theme('Topanga')

def layout_first():
layout = [[sg.Text('Pozadina'), sg.Button('          ', button_color=('black', 'lightblue'), 
key='bb'), sg.Button('          ', button_color=('black', 'lightgrey'), key='bg')],
          [sg.Text('Tijelo'), sg.Button('          ', button_color=('black', 'white'), 
key='tw'), sg.Button('          ', button_color=('black', 'lightpink'), key='tp')],
          [sg.Button('KRENI', disabled=True, key='go')]]
return layout
dalje = 1
sve = 0
bb = 'lightblue'
bg = 'lightgrey'
tw = 'white'
tp = 'lightpink'
win = sg.Window('',layout_first())
while True:
    if sve == 2:
        win.Element('go').Update(disabled=False)
    e, v = win.read()
    if e == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        dalje = 0
        win.close()
        break
    if e == 'bb':
        pozadina = bb
        win.Element('bb').Update(disabled=True)
        win.Element('bg').Update(visible=False)
        sve += 1
        continue
    if e == 'bg':
        pozadina = bg
        win.Element('bb').Update(visible=False)
        win.Element('bg').Update(disabled=True)
        sve += 1
        continue
    if e == 'tw':
        tijelo = tw
        win.Element('tw').Update(disabled=True)
        win.Element('tp').Update(visible=False)
        sve += 1
        continue
    if e == 'tp':
        tijelo = tp
        win.Element('tp').Update(disabled=True)
        win.Element('tw').Update(visible=False)
        sve += 1
        continue
    if e == 'go':
        win.close()
        break
if dalje:
    try:
        area=Screen()
        area.title('Moj prijatelj')
        speed(speed=0)
        if tijelo == tw:
            color(tijelo)
        else:
            color(tijelo)
        if pozadina == bb:
            area.bgcolor(pozadina)
        else:
            area.bgcolor(pozadina)
        pencolor('black')
        var = 480
        begin_fill()
        for i in range(var):
            forward(pi)
            right(360/var)
        for i in range(int(var/2)):
            forward(pi)
            left(720/var)
        end_fill()
        penup()
        left(90)
        forward(var/4)
        left(90)
        forward(var/10)
        pendown()
        begin_fill()
        color('black')
        for i in range (int(var/8)):
            forward(pi)
            right(2880/var)
        end_fill()
        penup()
        right(90)
        forward(var/8)
        right(90)
        forward(var/5)
        pendown()
        begin_fill()
        color('black')
        for i in range (int(var/8)):
            forward(pi)
            right(2880/var)
        end_fill()
        right(90)
        penup()
        forward(var/8)
        right(90)
        forward(var/16)
        color('orange')
        pencolor('black')
        pendown()
        begin_fill()
        forward(var/15)
        left(100)
        forward(var/6)
        right(203)
        forward(var/6)
        end_fill()
        penup()
        goto(0,300)
        style = ('Helvetica', 30)
        write('Moj prijatelj Snješko', font=style, align='center')
        hideturtle()
        done()
    except:
        dalje = 0
```

Comment: Why not just use pure `tkinter`. Both `pysimplegui` and `turtle` were deigned to make it easier for new programmers not very practical for building applications with it.

Comment: PySimpleGUI and turtle have different settings on tkinter root window when import and some calls, so `done()` will work different after you used PySimpleGUI.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Turtle.py

Comment: @JasonYang thanks man, dosen't look exactly like i wanted in the begining, in a way maybe its even better, but most importantly works :)